# Repair for rotted flooring/subfloor

Tags: basement, flooring

Any tips on how to repair this ?  Just this section was rotted and don't have extra flooring anymore.

[image: Picture of issue]

Comment: We really need you to put more words up there describing what's in that photo. It looks like coffee grounds from here. Also, it appears that there's water damage to the surrounding floor, so you need to be more clear about your overall goal. This looks like a complete tearout/replacement to me, but you may have other needs.

Comment: Once the leak is fixed and the rotten sub floor replaced, maybe use tile in that section as a design.  Matching it with similar wood flooring will probably look like a patch, unless you could cover it with something.

Comment: If you don't have flooring to match (sounds like you had some and disposed of it, or have used it all on other repairs, from your wording) then the repair won't match, or you'll have to redo the whole floor to have it match. Them's the breaks.

Comment: This question should be closed as it stands, but let's give the OP a bit of time to [edit] for clarity before doing so. That would be "nice", right?

Comment: No need to rush to close, agreed, @FreeMan *but we have certain people who love to rush to close, and if two more of them show up, there we go.*

Comment: Okay, I  wont vote to close just yet.

Comment: You might be able to "swipe" some matching floor boards from a closet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly suggest pulling up more of the finish flooring first to see how extensive the subfloor damage is. You'll most definitely want to repair all the subfloor before hiding it back under pretty wrapping paper. When you've got the flooring pulled up, if you're still not sure what to do, come back here, ask a *new* question, provide more pics and details about the situation, and I'm sure you'll get some great advice.

Then, when it comes time to put the finish flooring back down, you'll still be short a bit of flooring. Go to a closet or utility area or somewhere else that has this flooring but won't be as critical if it matches and swipe a few pieces from there.

You'll want to weave these new pieces in along the run somewhere so you don't have three boards with ends that line up right here - that'll be an obvious patch that will catch your eye, too.

Of course, you'll have to fill in the spots you stole from, but if it's in the corner of a closet, something that's the right size and *close* in terms of color will be good enough.